# How to send emails to multiple users using Laravel 7 Mail?

Tags: php, html, laravel, email, laravel-mail

This is my code which sends an email to a single address:

```
Route::get('/send-mail', function () {
$details = [
    'title' => 'Mail From KN7',
    'body' => 'Email test in Laravel SMTP'
];
\Mail::to('iamlegend707083@gmail.com')->send(new \App\Mail\TestMail($details));
echo "Email has been Sent!";
});
```

Is there any way to change this code so I can send the same email to multiple email addresses?

Comment: Do you want to send them separately (only 1 address in the To field), or all together (multiple addresses on the To field)

Comment: Wrap your `Mail::to()` in a loop of some kind (like looping over Users/email addresses you want to send to), or see if multiple addresses works (like `Mail::to(['address1', 'address2'])`), or use `->cc()` or `->bcc()` with the same logic.

Comment: @TimLewis Multiple addresses in the `Mail::to` would need to be sent as an array, so just needs the braces.

Comment: @aynber Cool, that's what I would have expected, but you never know :) Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @aynber I need to send all together (multiple addresses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add simple array :

```
 $usersArray = ['mail@gmail.com', 'mail2@gmail.com', 'mail3@gmail.com'];

    foreach($usersArray as $user){

        \Mail::to($user)->send(new \App\Mail\TestMail($details));
        echo "Email has been Sent!";
        });
    }
```

Comment: `Mail::to()` also accepts an array so no need for the `foreach()` loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array variables for multiple email IDs

```
Route::get('/send-mail', function () {
$details = [
    'title' => 'Mail From KN7',
    'body' => 'Email test in Laravel SMTP'
];
\Mail::to(['iamlegend707083@gmail.com','to_mail2@mail.com','to_mail3@mail.com'])->cc(['cc_mail1@mail.com','cc_mail2@mail.com'])->send(new \App\Mail\TestMail($details));
echo "Email has been Sent!";
});
```